# I have some date in my back end but node js displays one day less

Tags: node.js, angular, angular2-services

i have stored some dates in my database for example say **(2017-06-14)** but when the data is retrieved through node it shows something like this **'2017-06-13T18:30:00.000Z'**.can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

**why this shows the time one day before instead of displaying what is exactly stored in database**.

Comment: What timezone is the your computer in?

Comment: If you are not using some time-zone in your code than it will take the default server time. Check your server where the code is running.

Comment: I m using time Zone GMT +4:00

Comment: My problem is that how can i manage the code that it works on every GMT i.e it always shows the date which is exactly stored in database.